# Protect Delphi Connection String From Hack

Tags: sql-server, delphi, connection-string, ado

we have an delphi application that using tadoconnection for connecting sql server database 
a problem is when we open a resource hacker on running exe file it show's connectionstring clearly and any one can connect to our server

a sample code shown below describe problem
[image]

Comment: Are you running an SQL server with a direct connection to the internet that accepts arbitrary connections? If so then you need to hire a security expert. Imagining that you will be able to secure this yourself is delusional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not using a resource hacker. If your strings were stored in resources, they would be even easier to find and view.

You are using a memory scanner instead, one that looks at the program's raw memory while it is running.  Eventually, you would have to create a connection string in memory to pass to the database engine.  If a hacker has access to the app and its memory, they have app to its data. A *dedicated* hacker with such access will be able to grab that string at the time it is being used.

But there are things you can do to make things harder for *casual* hackers.

For one thing, don't allow non-admin users to have access to your app.  When a user runs the scanner app, it is likely to have access to memory in other apps run by the same user.  Run your app in a different user context, or in an elevated process.  Apps run by a user cannot access the memory of other apps being run by other users, unless he/she is explictly granted permission to them, or he/she is an admin to begin with.  If a hacker has permissions to access your app, all bets are off.

Also, break up the string into smaller substrings that you have to concatenate when needed. Build up the connection string dynamically. That way, the substrings are not stored in one place, should the hacker try looking through the EXE file itself on disk.

And by all means, **don't store sensitive credentials within the app code to begin with**.  Store them externally, and keep them encrypted.  Retrieve them to memory only when absolutely needed, and securely destroy the content of that memory using [`SecureZeroMemory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366877.aspx) when you are done using it.  If you need to hold on to the  credentials, or the connection string, in memory for more than a few milliseconds, consider using [`CryptProtectMemory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380262.aspx) to encrypt that memory when you are not actively using it.

The more work it takes you to piece together the connection string, the more work a casual hacker will have to do, too.  But a dedicated hacker will just wait until you do all the work, and then just pluck the final string from memory at the moment it is used, so you have to do what you can to prevent access to memory in the first place.

Comment: thanks dear remy we don't store sensitive credentials in app code and fetch it from windows service but after connecting we faced this problem that solved by moving it to adowillconnect

Answer (score 4):

1. Ensure your password is stored separately and as securely as meets your requirements.*
2. Ensure you do not persist your password with your connection. I.e. Connection.Properties must include `'Persist Security Info=False'`
3. Set `Connection.`[LoginPrompt](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TADOConnection.LoginPrompt) to `True`.
4. Implement a handler for the [OnLogin](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TCustomConnection.OnLogin) event in which you load, decrypt and provide your password to the `Connection.Open` call.
5. As a final security step, ensure you erase your decrypted password from memory.

> *There a plenty of simple encryption libraries available that you might as well encrypt your password. Microsoft's [Data Protection API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx) is worth considering. Bear in mind that perfect security is impossible if someone has access to your application. The best you can do is add layers of obfuscation making it more difficult for a hacker to crack your database login credentials.

Some sample code

```
procedure TAbc.HandleOnLogin(Sender: TObject; Username, Password: string);
var
  LPassword: string;
begin
  LPassword := GetDecryptedPassword; //Your choice how you do this
  Connection.Open(Username, LPassword);
  //The next line ensures memory is erased before it is deallocated
  //which would otherwise leave the password hanging around.
  SecureZeroMemory(Pointer(LPassword), Length(LPassword) * SizeOf(Char));
end;
```

Comment: Connection.Open(Username, LPassword); lead's to stack overflow

Comment: @dawoodkarimy You aren't meant to paste the code in blindly without trying to understand it. This is not much more than pseudo code.

Comment: i think onlogin event is not right place to handle password decryption onwilllogin event can handle it

Comment: I think this should not be the OnLogon but the OnWillConnect event. It allows you to specify/change username and password (both are var parameters) before the connection is actually made (even though the (Delphi 2007) help states it a bit confusingly) and before the logon dialog is shown (if at all) and before the call to OnLogon (which cannot change the username / password).

Comment: @dawood I'm going to packet sniff your program. How will you stop that?

Comment: it is not my case i only want to prevent showing clear user password in such applications if we want to solve packet sniff problem we should think to ssl and encryption

Comment: @dawoodkarimy Apologies for the confusion. I'll update with a complete example later when I have access to a compiler.

Comment: So you are happy for a hacker to discover the password with ease then?

Comment: Yes And You are Happy too for down vote all my question and answers!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers what you can do is remove permission to read process memory, this is useful if you control user permissions (say in enterprise environment).

Calling following procedure at the start of your process prevents non-admin user from reading process memory. (You'll need JEDI API units for missing API calls)

```
uses JwaWinNT, JwaWinBase, JwaAclApi, JwaAccCtrl;

//...
{$SCOPEDENUMS ON}
function ProtectProcess(): DWORD;
type
  TSidType = (Everyone, CurrentUser, System, Admin);
var
  // Released on exit
  ProcessToken: THandle;
  TokenInfo: PVOID;

  SidCurUser: PSID;
  SidEveryone: PSID;
  SidSystem: PSID;
  SidAdmins: PSID;

  ACL: PACL;
  SecDesc: PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR;
  Size: DWORD;
  TokenSize: DWORD;
  BResult: Bool;

  SIDAuthEveryone: SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY;
  SIDAuthSystem: SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY;
  SIDAuthAdministrators: SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY;

  SIDArray: array[TSidType] of PSID;
  I: TSidType;
const
  // Mimic Protected Process
  // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684880%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
  // Protected processes allow PROCESS_TERMINATE, which is
  // probably not appropriate for high integrity software.
  DeniedPermissions =
            {READ_CONTROL |}
            WRITE_DAC or WRITE_OWNER or
            PROCESS_CREATE_PROCESS or PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD or
//            PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE or // this permission is needed for printing
            PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or
            PROCESS_SET_QUOTA or PROCESS_SET_INFORMATION or
            PROCESS_VM_OPERATION or
            PROCESS_VM_READ or PROCESS_VM_WRITE
            // In addition to protected process
//            or PROCESS_SUSPEND_RESUME or PROCESS_TERMINATE
            ;
  // Standard and specific rights not explicitly denied
  AllowedPermissions = ((not DeniedPermissions) and $1FFF) or PROCESS_TERMINATE or SYNCHRONIZE;
begin
  ACL := nil;
  TokenInfo := nil;
  SecDesc := nil;
  try
    TokenSize := 0;
    ProcessToken := 0;
    // If this fails, you can try to fallback to OpenThreadToken
    if (not OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_READ, ProcessToken)) then
    begin
      Result := GetLastError();
      Exit;
    end;

    BResult := GetTokenInformation(ProcessToken, TokenUser, nil, 0, TokenSize);
    Result := GetLastError();
    Assert((not BResult) and (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = Result));
    if(not ((BResult = FALSE) and (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = Result))) then
    begin
      // failed;
      Exit;
    end;

    if (TokenSize > 0) then
    begin
      TokenInfo := HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, TokenSize);
      Result := GetLastError();
      Assert(Assigned(TokenInfo));
      if (nil = TokenInfo) then
      begin
        // failed;
        Exit;
      end;
    end;

    BResult := GetTokenInformation(ProcessToken, TokenUser, TokenInfo, TokenSize, TokenSize);
    Result := GetLastError();
    Assert(BResult and Assigned(TokenInfo));
    if not (BResult and Assigned(TokenInfo)) then
    begin
      Exit;
    end;

    SidCurUser := (PTokenUser(TokenInfo)).User.Sid;

    SIDAuthEveryone := SECURITY_WORLD_SID_AUTHORITY;
    BResult := AllocateAndInitializeSid(@SIDAuthEveryone, 1,
        SECURITY_WORLD_RID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SidEveryone);
    Result := GetLastError();
    Assert(BResult and Assigned(SidEveryone));
    if not (BResult and Assigned(SidEveryone)) then
    begin
      Exit;
    end;

    SIDAuthSystem := SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
    BResult := AllocateAndInitializeSid(@SIDAuthSystem, 1,
        SECURITY_LOCAL_SYSTEM_RID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SidSystem);
    Result := GetLastError();
    Assert(BResult and Assigned(SidSystem));
    if not (BResult and Assigned(SidSystem)) then
    begin
      Exit;
    end;

    SIDAuthAdministrators := SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
    BResult := AllocateAndInitializeSid(@SIDAuthAdministrators, 2,
        SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID, DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SidAdmins);
    Result := GetLastError();
    Assert(BResult and Assigned(SidAdmins));
    if not (BResult and Assigned(SidAdmins)) then
    begin
      Exit;
    end;

    SIDArray[TSidType.Everyone] := SidEveryone;   // Deny most rights to everyone
    SIDArray[TSidType.CurrentUser] := SidCurUser; // Allow what was not denied
    SIDArray[TSidType.System] := SidSystem;       // Full control
    SIDArray[TSidType.Admin] := SidAdmins;        // Full control

    // Determine required size of the ACL
    Size := SizeOf(ACL);

    // First the DENY, then the ALLOW
    Size := Size + GetLengthSid(SIDArray[TSidType.Everyone]);
    Size := Size + SizeOf(ACCESS_DENIED_ACE) - SizeOf(DWORD);

    for I := TSidType.CurrentUser to High(SIDArray) do
    begin
      // DWORD is the SidStart field, which is not used for absolute format
      Size := Size + GetLengthSid(SIDArray[I]);
      Size := Size + SizeOf(ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE) - SizeOf(DWORD);
    end;

    Size := Size + SizeOf(DWORD);

    ACL := PACL(HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, Size));
    Result := GetLastError();
    Assert(Assigned(ACL));
    if not Assigned(ACL) then
    begin
      Exit;
    end;

    BResult := InitializeAcl(ACL, Size, ACL_REVISION);
    Result := GetLastError();
    Assert(BResult);
    if not BResult then
    begin
      Exit;
    end;

    BResult := AddAccessDeniedAce(ACL, ACL_REVISION, DeniedPermissions,
      SIDArray[TSidType.Everyone]);
    Result := GetLastError();
    Assert(BResult);
    if not BResult then
    begin
      Exit;
    end;

    BResult := AddAccessAllowedAce(ACL, ACL_REVISION, AllowedPermissions,
      SIDArray[TSidType.CurrentUser]);
    Result := GetLastError();
    Assert(BResult);
    if not BResult then
    begin
      Exit;
    end;

    // Because of ACE ordering, System will effectively have dwAllowed even
    // though the ACE specifies PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS (unless software uses
    // SeDebugPrivilege or SeTcbName and increases access).
    // As an exercise, check behavior of tools such as Process Explorer under XP,
    // Vista, and above. Vista and above should exhibit slightly different behavior
    // due to Restricted tokens.
    BResult := AddAccessAllowedAce(ACL, ACL_REVISION, PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,
      SIDArray[TSidType.System]);
    Result := GetLastError();
    Assert(BResult);
    if not BResult then
    begin
      Exit;
    end;

    // Because of ACE ordering, Administrators will effectively have dwAllowed
    // even though the ACE specifies PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS (unless the Administrator
    // invokes 'discretionary security' by taking ownership and increasing access).
    // As an exercise, check behavior of tools such as Process Explorer under XP,
    // Vista, and above. Vista and above should exhibit slightly different behavior
    // due to Restricted tokens.
    BResult := AddAccessAllowedAce(ACL, ACL_REVISION, PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, SIDArray[TSidType.Admin]);
    Result := GetLastError();
    Assert(BResult);
    if not BResult then
    begin
      SiMain.LogWin32Error('AddAccessAllowedAce failed: ', Result);
      Exit;
    end;

    SecDesc := PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR(HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH));
    Result := GetLastError();
    Assert(Assigned(SecDesc));
    if not Assigned(SecDesc) then
    begin
      Exit;
    end;

    // InitializeSecurityDescriptor initializes a security descriptor in
    // absolute format, rather than self-relative format. See
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378863(VS.85).aspx
    BResult := InitializeSecurityDescriptor(SecDesc, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
    Result := GetLastError();
    Assert(BResult);
    if not BResult then
    begin
      Exit;
    end;

    BResult := SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(SecDesc, TRUE, ACL, FALSE);
    Result := GetLastError();
    Assert(BResult);
    if not BResult then
    begin
      Exit;
    end;

    SetSecurityInfo(
        GetCurrentProcess(),
        SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, // process object
        OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION or DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
        SidCurUser, // Owner SID
        nil, // Group SID
        ACL,
        nil // SACL
        );
    Result := GetLastError();
    Assert(ERROR_SUCCESS = Result);
  finally
    if (nil <> SecDesc) then
    begin
      HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, SecDesc);
    end;
    if (nil <> ACL) then
    begin
      HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, ACL);
    end;
    if (SidAdmins <> nil) then
    begin
      FreeSid(SidAdmins);
    end;
    if (SidSystem <> nil) then
    begin
      FreeSid(SidSystem);
    end;
    if (SidEveryone <> nil) then
    begin
      FreeSid(SidEveryone);
    end;
    if (nil <> TokenInfo) then
    begin
      HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, TokenInfo);
    end;
    if (0 <> ProcessToken) then
    begin
      CloseHandle(ProcessToken);
    end;
  end;
end;
```